# Haproxy: try different backend if 404

Tags: haproxy

I have a haproxy server with several backends behind it. Backends are picked with round-robin; anyway I need it to try other backends, if it gets 404 from the selected one.

If 404 is returned from all reachable backends, haproxy should return 404 to the client.

Is that possible?

Comment: I think you'll find it easier to make sure your backends are capable of delivering the same content.  If not, what's the use of load-balancing?  I've been working with haproxy for quite a number of years now, but I wouldn't know if what you're asking is possible, sorry.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - I'm trying to handle ACME http-01 challenge on a cluster of servers, so each has the shared DNS name in SAN. It's perfectly possible with nginx...

Comment: Haproxy could very well answer the challenge itself, or else know which backends could.

Comment: If you have 5 haproxy servers, `lb01-5`, with a shared name `lb`, and need to request 5 certs with `CN=lb0[1-5];SAN=lb`, how would you do it? If `lb05` is doing verification, but `lb01` has the shared IP, lb01 can't answer the challenge for `lb05`.

Comment: On my 2 haproxy servers, I have the certificates of all the domains we host (if  one goes down, the other takes over its IP and does all the work).  The haproxy's do SSL offloading before the traffic passes to the backends via http.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible(as of now).

HAProxy retries another backend server when there are errors before the request was sent, for example, connection timeout. If the connection is established with one backend server and request is sent, even one byte, HAProxy will not try to use another backend server.

Answer (score 1):

No.
`option redispatch` is the closest thing HAProxy has, but it will only retry a different back-end if `retries` is > 0 and the connection to the backed fails. It doesn't care about the HTTP status code from the backend, it just cares if the backed in down (can't be reached, no response)

Comment: I am fine with nginx so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,if I have properely understood, with the option

```
option httpchk GET /../CheckHealth.html
http-check disable-on-404
```

Where CheckHealth.html should be a reachable resource sample, if the resource is not found and a 404 error recieved, the node has been set in "active or backup SOFT STOPPED for maintenance" and the roundrobin never send request again to that node switching to the others only.

Something like :

```
 backend backend_servers
 balance            roundrobin
 option httpchk GET /.../CheckHealth.html
 http-check disable-on-404
 server             www01 XX:YY:ZZ:KK:8180 check
 server             www02 XX:YY:ZZ:MM:8180 check
 server         www03 XX:YY:ZZ:FF:8180 check
```

will fail on www02 because there is no WAR deploied there, and balance on www01, www03 with no failure shown to the client.